# How to repeat a word or line

Tags: text-processing

How can repeat a word or line on a number of lines, like the command `foo` in

```
$ foo 3 word 
word
word
word
```

or

```
$ foo 2 An example line
An example line
An example line
```

with the same effect like

```
$ seq 3 | sed s/./word/
word
word
word
```

or

```
$ yes word | head -3
word
word
word
```

I had expected that `seq` supports that, but it does not, as far as I see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any external utilities to do that, but just use your native shell's internals with `printf()` functionality. For e.g. in a `bash` shell, you could do

```
foo() {
    if [ "$1" -lt 2 ]; then
        printf '%s\n' 'insufficient arguments provided' >&2
    fi

    local iter
    for (( iter = 1; iter <= $1; iter++ )); do
        printf '%s\n' "$2"
    done
}
```

Make sure to quote the word to be printed under quotes, so that the words are not split. E.g.

```
foo 3 bar
foo 3 'howdy world'
```

---

If you are looking for an external utility for the same, `perl` or `awk` can just do it as needed

```
printf '%s\n' 'howdy world' | perl -ne 'print $_ x 3'
```

or

```
printf '%s\n' 'howdy world' | awk '{ for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) print $0 }'
```

Also BSD systems have a binary `jot` which can just repeat strings provided to it. Or in Ubuntu systems under `athena-jot` package.

```
jot -b 'howdy world' 3
```

Comment: That approach works, but that would mean to build it myself. It would be faster than the two implementations I gave, but somewhat more complex. I think there must be a command that can do it alone.

Comment: @VolkerSiegel: The function gave uses nothing but the shell internals and no overhead at all. Any other external forked processes cannot match up to this

Comment: @VolkerSiegel: You can just add the function in `.bashrc` and just call it from the command line as you want

Comment: It is, in itself, faster for a single call and small number arguments. I'm not sure about many lines.

Comment: @VolkerSiegel: Which OS are you in Linux or BSD?

Comment: Linux. I'll go try whether 2 processes are slower.

Comment: I'm not saying your solution is wrong or bad. But It's academically interesting whether it is actually faster in a practical sense. There is of course a difference between interactive and script use.

Comment: Yes! `jot` is exactly the command I am looking for!  I started to give up the thought that it must exist for sure... I have it in Ubuntu!

Comment: It's in the Ubuntu package `athena-jot`.

Comment: @VolkerSiegel: Added a note

Comment: It's actually worth being the first on top! That you found it is actually pretty emotional for me. I know UNIX in general pretty well. I have developed something like trust in it on the conceptual level. So I was sure this must exist... and it felt really deeply wrong that this does not exist. Now, it's only absurdly unknown, saves my worldview, thanks for digging it up.

Answer (score 1):

`tcsh` and `zsh` have `repeat`:

```
repeat 3 echo word
```

With `printf`, you could do:

```
printf 'word\n%.0s' {1..3}
```